# Should app allow user to switch iCloud on or off?

Tags: icloud

The Apple documentations says:

> When a user launches your iCloud-enabled app for the first time,
>   invite them to use iCloud.
>
> Never prompt the user again about
>   whether they want to use iCloud vs. local storage.

What if the user does not pick iCloud the first time, but decides to use it later?

What if after using iCloud for a few days, the user decides to switch back to local storage?

What if a user runs out of iCloud storage space, but does not want to pay for additional space?

Should an app be designed to allow users to toggle between local and iCloud storage? If yes, what's the best way to deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely need to be able to migrate a user between the two storage methods, for the reasons you include above plus more - what if the user signs out of iCloud? And what if that is followed by another iCloud user signing in? You need to handle this stuff and be able to move things when you can and even when you can't do that, save stuff in the right place and where the user expects.

How you handle it will depend on what types of iCloud storage you are using. For the key value store, you should also be caching that stuff locally (it's not an NSUserDefaults substitute).

For document and Core Data, you can sometimes migrate persistent stores back into local stores, and you can sometimes move documents out of iCloud to local storage. I'd recommend reading both the Document Programming on iOS guide and the iCloud guide to get at least a base idea of how to handle this.

One thing that can be tough is detecting some of these changes - the APIs are a bit underbaked in this regard. One technique that is used by some are 'sentinel files' that you place in ubiquity - if they're missing, you know that the iCloud universe as you knew it has changed.

Take a look at how Apple's apps handle this, like iWork. There's an iCloud switch in their settings bundle.